# How to setup joomla live website to local?

Tags: php, joomla

I want to setup Joomla live website to localhost. I changed in `configuration.php` file like:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'root';
public $password = '';
public $db = 'myjoodb';
```

and also changed in:

```
public $log_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/jooFolder/logs';
public $tmp_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/jooFolder/tmp';
```

when I hit the URL `localhost/jooFolder` then its not show any error or even not show my website. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the XAMPP service currently running?

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. yes i have xampp service.

Comment: changing some php vars won't matter if your webserver isn't configured correctly, e.g. setting the proper document root.

Comment: May you please elaborate so that i am able to do that?

Comment: The homepage si totally blank ? Could you show the complete configuration.php file ?

Comment: Have you actually created your database on your local environment?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try:

- Make sure there is no .htaccess file in your website route. That can cause problems.
- Can you get to the administrator login? (localhost/jooFolder/administrator) If you can get to here and login you might be able to do some more diagnostics...

Answer (score 0):

Have u created and imported the database in PHP mySQL on your local computer? if yes then can you make sure that the database prefix is same as per your server and if you get a new database prefix then you need to change the database prefix in your configuration file. 

If everything is fine then Just like Daniel said, 
If you have .htaccess file in your website directory (localhost/jooFolder) then it can cause problem, if I face this problem the first thing I check iss .htaccess file in root directory and if I have then change it to htaccess.tmp and get my website live. 
Also as per Daniel if you can access Administrator panel then log in and go to System -> Global Configuration -> Error reporting from None to Maximum and refresh your website front page and see if you get any error message.